# Using single quotes in an In statement with a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am missing something about single quotes and in statements that would be very helpful.

```
Select *
from list
where first_name in ('JAMES','JACK');
```

returns the list of all people with the first name of James and Jack.

However, when doing:

```
Select *
from list
where first_name in (:names);
```

What do I have to set the names variable to?
I've tried what seems like infinite combinations of '''JAMES'',''JACK''' ETC in order to get rid of the single quotes issue, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You can not use IN clause like that on variable containing comma separated values. Your best bet is to write a function which returns table containing individual names as rows and use them inside the IN condition. See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243188/passing-a-variable-into-an-in-clause-within-a-sql-function

Comment: Also, `:names` does not seem like sql server parameter. parameters in sql server starts with an at sign: `@names`.

Comment: Here are some correct ways of quoting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15442322/4780877

Comment: another way of explaining what @Harsh wrote - the `In` operator expects a comma separated list of values, while you supply it with a single value that contains a comma separated list.

Comment: Ah, i'm also working with oracle for other parts so sometimes i do different variations.
So I have to create a temporary table/view with say column title name and give it elements 'JAMES' and 'JACK' then use the in statement for that view?

Comment: Have a look at the link I posted in my earlier comment to see how to convert list of CSV strings into table valued function and use it in queries such as yours.

Comment: The only other option would be to give a variable for each name you wanted to find, if you are writing a stored procedure there would be no problem with multiple variables...

Comment: I would also propose to do something like this: `first_name in (@name1, @name2, @name3)`

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to parse this through as a parameter

```
Declare @name as varcher (8000)
Set @name = 'Jack,James,John,Jill'

Select *
from list
where first_name in (@names);
```

or

```
Select *
from list
where first_name in ('Jack','James','John','Jill');
```